# More efficient to do SELECT and compare in Java or DELETE and INSERT

Tags: update, insert, java

I am hitting a REST API to get data from a service. I transform this data and store it in a database. I will have to do this on some interval, 15 minutes, and then make sure this database has latest information.
I am doing this in a Java program. I am wondering if it would be better, after I have queried all data, to do:

1. SELECT statements and compare vs transformed data and do UPDATEs (DELETE all associated records to what was changed and INSERT new)

OR

2. DELETE ALL and INSERT ALL every time.

Option 1 has potential to be a lot less transactions, guaranteed SELECT on all records because we are comparing, but potentially not a lot of UPDATEs since I don't expect data to be changing much. But it has downside of doing comparisons on all records to detect a change

I am planning on doing this using Spring Boot, JPA layer and possibly postgres

Comment: Could you specify the DBMS involved, at least?

Comment: Please do [not crosspost](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068/157328)

Answer (score 0):

Neither of your proposals can be considered efficient. `MERGE` was introduced a long time ago (SQL99 or SQL2003) and will outperform both of your alternatives:

```
MERGE INTO T as x
USING (
    VALUES (?, ...., ?)
) as y (c1, c2, ...,cn)
    ON x.<key> = y.<key>
WHEN MATCHED AND (x.c1, x.c2, x....) <> (y.c1,y.c2, y...) THEN 
    UPDATE (...)
    VALUES (y..)
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT (...)
    VALUES (...)
```